# Generating URL for Controller action in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How can I dynamically create an URL for a Controller action?

Consider the following case:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("controller")
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping("url")
    public String method() {
        return "Whatever"
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is get the base URL and concat controller/url to it.
For this behavior, Laravel for example provides the URL helper (action() method). Is there something similar in Spring Boot?

Comment: Could you elaborate more with example

Comment: Could you look at my answer?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [UriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) to get the current url and concat the additional part to it

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("controller")
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping("url")
    public String method(UriComponentBuilder ucb) {
        URI uri = ucb.path("/url").build().toUri();
        return "Whatever"
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to generate that URL outside that Controller.

Comment: u mean, outside of the any method where the request is mapped?

Comment: To map a request somewhere, you need to know the location of somewhere. That location is the URL, hence I want to be able to generate the URL of somewhere.

Comment: yeah,the application must have at least one known mapping. Once the request comes there, you can simply use `return "redirect:/user?url=website.com"` to pass it to any other controller method by passing any request parameters/path variables. You don't really require the complete url unless you are passing to a different application. The relative path will suffice if you are redirecting it within the same application.

Comment: Yeah, but that means I have to remember whether a given controller has a special URL mapping or not.

Comment: as far as I know, there should be at least one known mapping. Otherwise, spring wont be able to figure out which method should handle the request. Once, the request comes to controller, it can then be routed to any mapped url across the application

Answer (score 2):

There is a library present for spring boot framework. Which you need to add in your project in order to generate link dynamically. The gradle dependency of this library is given below.

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:2.1.4.RELEASE'
```

I am assuming your build system is gradle but if you are using maven then please use below syntax.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

After than you can generate link dynamically as below.

```
WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(Controller.class).slash("url").withSelfRel().getHref();
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Tushar's answer, this is my approach to generating URLs by name with some sanity to prevent a load of broken links:

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder;

public final class ControllerUtils {

    public static String getActionUrl(Class<?> cls, String name) {
        return WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(cls).slash(name).withSelfRel().getHref();
    }
}
```

```
public class MyController {

    public static final String URL_RESULTS = "results";
    
    @PostMapping
    public String handleForm() {
      var nextUrl = ControllerUtils.getActionUrl(this.getClass(), URL_RESULTS);
      response.sendRedirect(nextUrl);
    }

    @GetMapping("/" + URL_RESULTS)
    @ResponseBody
    public String results() { .... }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think using @PathVariable will help you

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/controller")
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value="/url/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String method(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
         System.out.println("the url value : "+id );
        return "Whatever"
    }
}
```

then you can call the method using /controller/url/{here the value}
example /controller/url/www.google.com

Comment: That's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to map only Controller , using a property file

application.properties

```
server.context-path=/rest
```

If your Controllers are serving Data from a Repository, then Spring Data REST can take out much of the boilerplate & solve your initial problem.

**[Spring Data REST](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_changing_the_base_uri)**

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can control the base URL by using a property file.

application.properties

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/rest
```

That's you want /rest concat controller/url